# Django AttributeError

Tags: django

I keep getting Attribute Error

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

It points to: `order_number = response.get('order_number',0)`

Here are the related files in my `checkout` app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `def process(request)` returns nothing. So response is always `None`. It should return a response.

Answer (score 1):

change your process function to this

```
def process(request):
    order = create_order(request)
    results = {'order_number':order.id,'message':''}
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    amount = cart.cart_subtotal(request)
    return results
```